# While , Automating calculator,I had a following error?

Tags: android, appium-android

A new session could not be created.

> [error: No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set android Package to launch pre-existing app on device)

## While running code with `appium` using `eclipse`, I had this error.

```
public class FirstAppiumProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "");
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,Platform.ANDROID);
   dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
    dc.setCapability("APP_PACKAGE", "com.android.calculator2");
    dc.setCapability("APP_ACTIVITY", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
   dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Nexus 5");
   WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new 
   URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),dc);    
   System.out.println(dc.toString());
   driver.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: is your appium server running ?

Comment: Yes , its running , but when i run the java application its giving me error.

Comment: Can you try to run calculator from command (Google how to open an app using adb command) and see if app is opening or not

Comment: Are you sure package and activity are correct? It may change depending on the device

Comment: i have an error as -avd is offline ?

Comment: make sure you have adb path set..check by running command 'adb devices'

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is because your capabilities are set wrongly.
At least appPackage and appActivity.

Read how [capabilities](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) are. Your possible capabilities:

```
//Your capabilities should be something like this:
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
dc.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
dc.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 5");
dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
```

Give it a try and let me know if you made it work

Comment: yes , it was related to capabilities.now its working fine. Thanks to all